# Mathematica: Unusual piecewise plot issue

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica

Hello and thanks in advance,

I came upon an issue trying to plot a piecewise function in Mathematica. When entered directly into the Plot function, the piecewise did NOT plot. However, when I defined the piecewise as a variable, it did plot. Why is this issue occurring and can I still join my plot? (I would like to join it by setting exclusions to none)

The following is my code: (I define a Maxwell strain function and am trying to model the plastic deformation of a polymer over multiple stress cycles)

```
z = 2*10^10;  
h = 10^12;  
MaxwellStrain[s_, t_] := s/z + (s*t)/h;  
stress = {0, 10^7, -10^7, 5*10^6, 10^7, -5*10^6};  
time = {0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500};  
strainList = Join[{0}, Table[MaxwellStrain[stress[[i + 1]], t - time[[i]]], {i, 1, 5}]];

Plot[
 Piecewise[
  Table[{
    Total[strainList[[1 ;; i + 1]]], time[[i]] < t < time[[i + 1]]},
   {i, 1, 5}
   ],
  Exclusions -> none]
 ,
 {t, 0, 500}
 ]

x = Piecewise[
  Table[{
    Total[strainList[[1 ;; i + 1]]], time[[i]] < t < time[[i + 1]]},
   {i, 1, 5}
   ],
  Exclusions -> none]

Plot[x, {t, 0, 500}]
```

The following is my output: (first plot doesn't show, the second does)

output:
[image: output - screenshot]

Thank you for the help,
SV

Comment: try doing `Evaluate@Piecewise[ .. `

Comment: @agentp thanks! it worked